# decode image data from a HTTP string response. (Elm 0.18)

Tags: image, http, elm, binary-data

I'd like to fetch an image from a remote server and load it into the following data structure:

```
type alias Pixel = { r : Int, g : Int, b: Int, a: Float }
type alias ImageData = { pixels : Array Pixel, width: Int }
```

In the project for some reasons I'm still using Elm 0.18, and `elm-lang/http` only let's you handle strings as responses from http requests.

```
init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( {}
    , Http.send
        (\response ->
            case response of
                Ok data ->
                    let
                        _ =
                            Debug.log "ok" data
                    in
                    NoOp

                Err error ->
                    let
                        _ =
                            Debug.log "error" error
                    in
                    NoOp
        )
        (Http.getString "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/Creamer_MET_186969.jpg/2px-Creamer_MET_186969.jpg")
    )
```

This logs:

```
ok: "����\0C\0\n\r\t\n\n\r\r��\0\v\0\0\"\0��\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\n\v��\0�\0\0\0}\0!1AQa\"q2���#B��R��$3br�\t\n%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������\0\0\0?\0�9�(�.t�/���=~���"
```

But how to convert it into the above data structure? Also, does it matter if the image is a jpg, png, gif?

What I'm looking for is the implementation of a function `imageDataFromString : String -> Maybe ImageData`

*note: I'd prefer a non-port solution even if performance will be lower, the images I'm trying to process are not large.*

Comment: If you want to do this without ports you have a pretty big task ahead of you. It's not simply a matter of re-encoding the data. Once you have it in a binary format it also needs to be parsed and decompressed according to the file format. There's some really advanced stuff going into some of these image formats to make their file size small and I doubt there's any implementation of these algorithms in Elm 0.18 since it doesn't even have a standard way of representing binary data.

Comment: I think I'd do the entire request through a port. Pass in am image URL, get pixel data back. With a good js image processing library this shouldn't involve too much code of your own I think.

Comment: alright, sounds convincing. and for the future.. in elm19, would you suggest to use ports as well or might there be an elm only solution?

Comment: Yes, because although Elm 0.19 does have a standard representation for binary format, in elm/bytes, I don't think there is any library for extracting pixel data from various image formats, since that is a very significant task i itself. Although if you have the time, it would be an interesting and worthwhile project to work on.

Comment: thanks for the comments! They've been actually answers, so feel free to put them there.

Comment: To extract the actual pixels I would just draw the image to a `canvas` element via [`drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and get the `rgba`-values via [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). No JavaScript library required and with only a few lines of code. Keep in mind, though, that the decompressed data will take up more space than the actual file.